# Sql converting 'this' to query result

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to make query, which will replace hours(when its 23 its gonna be output " from 23 to 00"), but I don't wanna make duplicated code, so trying to find solution for all other hours(from 00, to 22).
In my mind it sounds like(take 'this' and output 'FROM'+ this + 'TO' + this+1)
Is it possible?

And please, help me with count columnt(CNT) for each user, I only made this counting all mesages, not for each users(I think I should use right join?)

Structure looks like that:

[image]

My code is:

```
SELECT a.C_NAME as abonent, 
CASE
WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM C_EXEC_TIME) = 23 THEN 'FROM 23 TO 00'
WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM C_EXEC_TIME) IN (1,3,5,13) THEN 'FROM H TO H+1'
END HH24,
count(C_ST) as CNT
FROM ST_ABONENTS a, QRY_QUEUE qq
WHERE C_EXEC_TIME IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY a.c_NAME, EXTRACT(HOUR FROM C_EXEC_TIME)
ORDER BY a.c_name;
```

My result now:

[image]

It shows ABONENT, HOUR(when this abonent has activity), COUNT(of messages, now it shows all mesages per hour for all abonents)

Desired result:

[image]

Data samples:

[image][image][image]

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  edited: added data samples and desired result, content of C_NAMEs means 'Message type №' in QRY_TYPE, and 'Abonent№' in ST_ABONENTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THE SOLUTION IS:

```
SELECT a.C_NAME as abonent, 
CASE
WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM C_EXEC_TIME) = 23 THEN 'С 23 до 00'
ELSE concat(concat('С ',TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM C_EXEC_TIME))),concat(' до ', TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM C_EXEC_TIME)+1)))
END HH24,
round(count(C_ST)/60/60*10,2) as CNT
FROM ST_ABONENTS a
inner join qry_type qt on a.id = qt.c_ab_ref
inner join qry_queue qq on qt.id = qq.c_qry_type
WHERE C_EXEC_TIME IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY a.c_NAME,  EXTRACT(HOUR FROM C_EXEC_TIME)
ORDER BY a.c_name, CNT desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

if other right

```
SELECT a.C_NAME as abonent, 
CASE
WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM C_EXEC_TIME) = 23 THEN 'FROM 23 TO 00'
ELSE 'FROM H TO H+1'
END HH24,
count(C_ST) as CNT
FROM ST_ABONENTS a, QRY_QUEUE qq
WHERE C_EXEC_TIME IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
a.c_NAME, 
CASE
WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM C_EXEC_TIME) = 23 THEN 'FROM 23 TO 00'
ELSE 'FROM H TO H+1'
END
ORDER BY a.c_name;
```